# Unable to return 301 using TomEE when redirecting from http to https

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, apache-tomee, http-status-code-302

Currently have a JSF web app deployed on apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4.  Have setup servlet.xml with the 8080 and 8443 Connectors and transport-guarantee CONFIDENTIAL section in web.xml to redirect all http requests to https.  This is working successfully.

Only problem is that it is returning a 302 (temporary) rather than 301 (permanent) response.

A fix is available for Tomcat 7.0.70 and beyond (59399) https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59399 which allowed you to specify a transportGuaranteeRedirectStatus="301" attribute against the Realm in the server.xml

I setup 7.0.70 with a simple web app, just using a single html file and basic web.xml with the security-constraint added, and this redirected successfully to 301.  When I dropped in the tomee.war file, installed tomee, then this reverted to 302.

Have also tried the latest 7.1.0 of TomEE but this also returns a 302.

Hoping that someone has overcome this using TomEE specifically as I know vanilla Tomcat is ok, and hopefully 1.7.4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sid you try a simple webapp with a jsp and no jsf? Does it work then?

Comment: Yes, tried with just html file, no WEB-INF/lib - the basic of the basic...still no joy

Comment: Ok, then you narrowed the cause down a little more and it is not JSF related then. I personally don't use TomEE so unfortunately for you, my help stops here.